# Android, when I must use syncronized in a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I'm at the beginning of a Java application. I've created a Service with some threads, but I haven't understood when I have to use synchronized and when not to.

For example, I have to connect with a bluetooth connection to a module, and then I use a Service with two threads: ConnectThread gives up the connection and ConnectedThread manages to read/write connection.

So when do I have to use synchronized?

Thank you

Comment: Multithreading in java is a very complex issue. It can only be understood through practice and reading of documentation or tutorials.

Comment: possible duplicate of [synchronized in java - Proper use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128997/synchronized-in-java-proper-use)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128997/synchronized-in-java-proper-use/24143267#24143267

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Synchronized keyword whenever you different threads are using the same (i.e. a global) variables(s), basically when information is being shared. Check the code to see if this is the case.

Synchronized is not needed when the variables each thread is using is local. Using it then would result in loss in performance and can result in inconsistoncies.

Comment: Mostly a good answer, but it could be improved.  Mutual exclusion (the most visible aspect of a `synchronized` block) is not _always_ needed just because two or more threads access the same data.  But, it is needed when one thread needs to put the data into a temporary invalid state that other threads must not be allowed to see.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid threads as much as possible as I am not that experienced with them but I'll try to explain it as simple as i can.

you only use synchronized if multiple threads have access to your method or block of code.

it is a simple solution to prevent other threads to access the same code  while another is still using it. this will help to prevent memory related problems but will cause performance issues. as synchronized codes are much slower than non synchronized code. also I Believe deadlocks might be an issue too

Comment: Threads don't _access_ code, they _execute_ it, and there is no inherent harm in allowing two or more threads to execute the same code at the same time.  It's not the code that matters:  Synchronization is all about _data_.   Mutual exclusion (i.e., what a `synchronized` block gives you) is needed when it is impossible for one thread to advance the state of the program without creating a temporary _invalid state_ that other threads must not be allowed to see.

Comment: great explanation @jameslarge ..thanks for clearing that up . Haven't really delivered my thought very well...