# Which properties of a method I can use to check if it is thread safe or not?

Tags: java, multithreading

For example I have the function as following:

```
public static final Function<A,B> MAP_A_TO_B(){
    return new Function<A,B>() {
        @Override
        public B apply(A) {
            switch (A) {
                case 1:
                    return B1;
                case 2:
                    return B2;
            }
            return B0;
        }
    };
}
```

But I don't know if it is thread safe or not, as my understand, since the method doesn't write to any class variable, it should be safe. Is my assumption correct ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which method are you referring to - `MAP_A_TO_B` or `apply`?

Comment: A method that only reads data can still not be threadsafe if it reads data that can be written by another thread. After all you'd have to analyze whether there could be at least one other thread that could alter the data a method is accessing directly or indirectly. In your case it would depend on what `B1` etc. are - if they could be replaced by another thread (e.g. someone could swap `B1` and `B2`) it would not be threadsafe.

Comment: @davmac I'm referring to the MAP_A_TO_B method

Comment: @Thomas The only variable I concern is the A, which is served as a parameter. Since my knowledge about java threading is limited, I wonder will it a problem is Thread 1 is using MAP_A_TO_B, then thread 2 calls the same method, but with different A object

Comment: Since you are using `switch()` `A` would have to be an enum or some kind of immutable object (e.g. a string) and thus it should be threadsafe. If two threads call the same method simultaneously both calls will run in their own frames (which contain the parameters and local values) and thus are independent there.

Comment: You should ideally use valid, compilable code in your example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128997/synchronized-in-java-proper-use/24143267#24143267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [davmac already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36420237/1391325), `MAP_A_TO_B()` is thread-safe because it always returns a new `Function<A,B>` object regardless of the state of the program. Likewise, this `Function<A,B>` object is thread-safe because it always performs the same logic: The only types which can be used in a switch statement are [primitive wrapper types, `String` and `Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)-- the first two are immutable and thus thread-safe and the last one is thread-safe because two different objects of the same `Enum` subtype cannot be equivalent (e.g. `Fruit.APPLE` and `Fruit.PEAR` will never be equivalent even if they have mutable states and happen to be in equivalent states --- such as if they had a non-final field `name` which was set to the same value).

However, instances of `B` must be assumed *not* to be thread-safe since we don't have any information about them in your example: Unless it is [defined](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09263/) as otherwise, [assume that code is *not* thread-safe](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/CON00-CPP.%20Avoid%20assuming%20functions%20are%20thread%20safe%20unless%20otherwise%20specified). Furthermore, even if a type's current *implementation* is thread-safe, if the type itself is not defined as such, this implementation may change to be non-thread-safe in the future and break code which depends on it being thread-safe.

Lastly, to be a pedant, it's better to define a "last-resort" switch case using the `default` case:

```
public B apply(A) {
    switch (A) {
        case 1:
            return B1;
        case 2:
            return B2;
        default:
            return B0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than think of thread safety being a property of a method, think of it as a property of an item of data.

To be thread safe, an item of data must be immutable, or all changes to it must be automatically published to all threads (by being volatile), or all accesses (reads and writes) must be guarded by the same lock (synchronized object), or the object must be set up in a static initializer and never changed thereafter.

[Java multi-threading & Safe Publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication)

Answer (score 1):

The `MAP_A_TO_B` method is perfectly threadsafe since it reads/modifies no state that is accessible to other threads.

Your code isn't actually compilable and the precise function of the `apply` method is a bit hazy:

```
   public B apply(A) {
```

The parameter must have a *name*.

```
                return B1;
```

If B is a type parameter, how can you be sure that `B1` is of the correct type?

If you were able to resolve these issues, the thread-safety of the `apply` method comes down to the `Bx` expressions. Do these access or modify state (variables) that is accessible to other threads?

Comment: I think he/she intends `B1`, `B2` etc. to be field names, since the method name `MAP_A_TO_B` shows that not only the names of (pseudo-)generic types are written in capitals.

Comment: @errantlinguist possibly, though there are no field declarations.

Comment: @errantlinguist I don't think I'm assuming otherwise? The lack of syntactic correctness here is factual, though. And `Bx` may indeed be fields, but they are still also expressions. Maybe I'm missing your point.

Comment: The original question wasn't why it's not compilable. Despite not being valid Java code, it still can be interpreted as a valid logical instruction set, and so I thought to myself: "Hmm, `Function<A,B>` is here, with just `A` as a parameter. He must not care about that parameter... but what about `B`?-- well, he returns `B1`, `B2` and so on, so he must be saying that those are different instances of type `B`." In other words, my brain didn't simply spit out `error: <identifier> expected` and stop working.

Comment: @errantlinguist ok, but nor did mine. I pointed out the syntactic problems, and also addressed the question. I don't think it's wrong to point out syntactic problems, especially when they are as significant as these ones. I try to avoid making any assumptions (such as what `B0` etc represent); I figure it's best to resolve ambiguities instead.

Comment: Okay, good point. I thought you were establishing a "if I don't see it, it must not be true" sort of thing...